# Which temp directory is used by SQLite VACUUM

Tags: sqlite, vacuum

When the SQLite VACUUM command is run pro grammatically, how to find which temporary directory is used while executing the command. I am using sqlite version 3.6.7
    I have this question because I get the following exception. So I want to check and if possible change the temporary directory that is used by the VACUUM.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_FULL]  Insertion failed because database is full (database or disk is full)

I tried monitoring the following directories (using java WatchService), but no files where changed in those directories by the VACUUM.
/var/tmp
/usr/tmp
/tmp
current directory

I tried executing PRAGMA temp_store_directory on the database, but go the following error(as it is not set/available):
java.sql.SQLException: query does not return ResultSet
```